# How can a spell that creates an emanation be modified not to affect allies?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

I want to make an emanation spell not hit allies, specifically the 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell *Darsson's fiery furnace* (*Shining South* 46). How can I do that?

Comment: [Of interest.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69828/8610)

Comment: Did you mean an Evocation spell?

Comment: Yes but it functions in an emanation area

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *spellguard rings* from *Complete Mage* come in pairs, and make the wearer of one immune to the spells of the wearer of the other. They’re not terribly expensive (4,000 gp), but you can only render as many allies immune as you have ring slots—and that means not wearing any other rings, and on top of that those allies also need to each give up a ring slot. Worse, they only function three times per day.

Note that it is possible to get up to five ring slots on a typical humanoid character: the [*hand of glory*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#handofGlory) neck slot item grants one for 8,000 gp, and the Extra Rings feat from *Eberron Campaign Setting* grants two more (but requires Forge Ring and caster level 12th).

Probably not the only or best way to do it, but it’s something to get your started.

Comment: The sculpting ability would be useful on a spell like *fireball*, but the spell OP wants to modify is already sculptable.  OP's problem is that the spell has a duration of 1 hour / level, and presumably OP's allies don't want to avoid the sculpted area of the spell for that duration.

Comment: No the answers were the ring is exactly what i wanted thanks alot :)

Comment: @DanB Per Avenger’s comment that the *spellguard rings* are the real answer to the question, I’ve eliminated the other non-fitting suggestions.

Comment: Would adding a *spellguard ring* effect to an existing *spellguard ring* for 6,000 gp *a la* the rules from the *Magic Item Compendium* make doing this more manageable?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Good point; I’ll edit that in. Though since *spellguard rings*’ price is for the pair, I’m not sure that 6,000 gp is right. I’m going to reread the entry tomorrow to see if there are any hints.