# What damaged a creature that is in an antimagic field from which it is excluded?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, feats, combat, antimagic-field

I read a lot about this topic, more precisely I base myself on what is stated here:

- [Does the feat Extraordinary Spell Aim affect the creature's space or the creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69828/does-the-feat-extraordinary-spell-aim-affect-the-creatures-space-or-the-creatur) (and other linked discussion)
- [What happens when an anti magic field gets close to a polymorphed creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/160568/what-happens-when-an-anti-magic-field-gets-close-to-a-polymorphed-creature)

but about the Extraordinary Spell Aim + [Anti magic field](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/antimagicField.htm) combo, I have not yet clear some points.

In all the following examples Jozan is a 15th level cleric with feat: Persistent Spell + Divine Metamagic applied to Persistent Spell + Extraordinary Spell Aim; and with [anti-magic field](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/antimagicField.htm) from which he is excluded

[As for the Extraordinary Spell Aim effect space](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69828/does-the-feat-extraordinary-spell-aim-affect-the-creatures-space-or-the-creatur), I agree with KRyan when he says that the PC is excluded from the spell's area, not the square where the PC is.

For example, if Jozan takes Vadania (*page 34, Player Handbook*) close into a grapple, Mialee can cast a Fireball with the certainty of not doing damage to the druid. The spell has no effect on Vadania but takes Jozan because Jozan is excluded from the anti magical field, and not the square he occupies.

But what else damage Jozan?

1. **Do all spells targeting Jozan take effect?** 
   Does [Magic Missile](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicMissile.htm) or [Ray of Enfeeblement](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/rayOfEnfeeblement.htm) or Streamers do damage? 
   What is the discriminate to understand which spell does damage and which doesn't?
2. **Do the magic weapons used against Jozan and out of his anti-magic field have bonuses of some kind for hitting and/or doing damage?**
   If Jozan is the target of an arrow, does he take damage if it is magical (for example if the arrow - and only this - is +1) or is fired by a magic bow (for example if the bow - and only this - is +1)? 
   Does the archer have a bonus to hit roll, or to damage and to hit roll or to damage or to neither of the two?
3. **Do the magic weapons used against Jozan and in of his anti-magic field have bonuses of some kind for hitting and/or doing damage?**
   If Jozan is the target of a Greatsword +1, would the enemy have advantages on his roll to hit or damage or both? 
   If an Assassin attacks Jozan using Wraithstrike does this spell take effect when Jozan is attacked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an *antimagic field* between you and a spellcaster does almost nothing for you—spells and spell areas can pass (suppressed) through the field to affect you on the other side. It does not break line of effect (or line of sight).

> 1. **Do all spells targeting Jozan take effect?** 
>      Does Magic Missile or Ray of Enfeeblement or Streamers do damage? 
>      What is the discriminate to understand which spell does damage and which doesn't?

Yes. Jozan is not subject to any antimagic effect, so he can be targeted freely. Spells can pass through the *antimagic field* in order to do so.

> 2. **Do the magic weapons used against Jozan and out of his anti-magic field have bonuses of some kind for hitting and/or doing damage?**
>      If Jozan is the target of an arrow, does he take damage if it is magical (for example if the arrow - and only this - is +1) or is fired by a magic bow (for example if the bow - and only this - is +1)? 
>      Does the archer have a bonus to hit roll, or to damage and to hit roll or to damage or to neither of the two?

If the wielder of those weapons is not within the *antimagic field*, then the *antimagic field* has no effect of any kind whatsoever on the situation.

If the wielder of those weapons is within the *antimagic field*, then the magic on those weapons is probably suppressed. The game isn’t super great about explaining this situation, since it would seem that the weapon would have to enter into the un-suppressed area in order to strike Jozan, but the “creature” based exception on Extraordinary Spell Aim probably actually means it does not, even as the weapon is cutting into him. If Jozan were simply standing next to an *antimagic field* and was attacked by someone within, this would be a much more uncertain situation.

> 3. **Do the magic weapons used against Jozan and in of his anti-magic field have bonuses of some kind for hitting and/or doing damage?**
>      If Jozan is the target of a Greatsword +1, would the enemy have advantages on his roll to hit or damage or both? 
>      If an Assassin attacks Jozan using Wraithstrike does this spell take effect when Jozan is attacked?

Magic weapon enhancement affects the weapon, and *wraithstrike* affects the attacker; neither affects the target. So what’s going on with Jozan has absolutely no relevance here. The question is whether or not the attacker is within the *antimagic field* or not—if they are, then the magic on them and their weapons is suppressed and offers no benefit. If they are not, then it is not, and Jozan is affected by them normally, the same as he would be if there is no *antimagic field* in play at all.

In short, Extraordinary Spell Aim on *antimagic field* is vastly, **vastly** less good than you think it is. It can still provide some benefit, if you can get your opponent inside the area themselves. But anyone outside the *antimagic field* has exactly the same ability to target and affect Jozan as they would if there was no *antimagic field*.